# Using Surefire to execute TestNG/Selenium tests in a jar

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, surefire

Our project has a suite of Selenium tests that we are currently packaging into a jar with the intent of Jenkins running the tests as a build step.  We install the jar into the local repository of a client VM that is configured to have Selenium point back to Jenkins as the host.  The trouble we are running into is figuring out a way to get Maven/SureFire to find the Selenium/TestNG tests in the jar we installed.  We have a pom with all the dependencies that the tests require on the client, including the jar of tests itself, but when we we run "mvn test" no tests are found.  Clearly we are missing something here, any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: It would be much better to create a `testng.xml` file with the listing of your tests. Surefire is naive and insufficient for recognizing tests. Let TestNG actually find them.

Answer (score 0):

surefire by default look for file names like Test*.java , *Test.java , *TestCase.java and executes them. if your test doesnt follow any of these pattern then you have to include them explicitly. [refer here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

Comment: To bad TestNG couldn't scan the source .jar file.  Hmm.  Maybe there is a way.

Comment: TestNG scans all files in the jar looking for `@Test` annotations. Surefire doesn't; it uses the less-flexible JUnit method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a main method calling testNG main method and pass your main methods  args[] to testNG Main method. Now your test jar will have main method of its to trigger test cases of your desire. You can pass the same paramteres as TestNG to your jar file like testng.xml file or -testClass classapath etc... see example below.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    org.testng.TestNG.main(arg);
}
```

now you just need to create a xml file of test classes and in jenkins use windows batch command to call your jar file on remote machine with required testNG parameters.